# Post jQuery dialog values to server in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I'm new to jQuery. I've got a dialog with several input boxes in it. I want the user to be able to hit a button and have the values posted back to the server - idealy to be picked up in a server event. What are the ways to achieve this?

Many thanks.

Comment: How do you want to use jquery?  Do you mean use jquery for the dialog component?

Comment: do you want o use ajax or can jquery just to a from submit?

Comment: I only want to use jQuery if possible. I need to get the values from the input form fields housed in the dialog and have then posted back to the server when the dialogs submit button is hit.
If there is a very good way of doing this that involves AJAX then I'd be willing to look at this too.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to be doing a postback, why can't you just use standard asp.net controls inside of your dialog? I've been using [jqModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/), and this seems to work fine.

I use a standard HTML input button to trigger the dialog (which is in the page as a hidden div). When the user clicks on the the asp.net button or controls in the dialog, the server doesn't know or care that the controls were in a modal dialog.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different approaches you could take.  You are probably going to want to use a jquery plugin.

I would look into [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/), its very easy to implement.  Other options would be using the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) plugin or [jQModal](http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/) depending on your needs. Each one offers some pros and cons.